# Regular Expression for Datetime

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for date time format “MM/DD/YY HH:mm:ss AM/PM” in asp.net regular expression validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315376/regular-expression-for-date-time-format-mm-dd-yy-hhmmss-am-pm-in-asp-net-reg)

Hi every one I need regular expression for dateTime.
Acceptable datetime is "03/14/2012 04:02 PM"
Using RequiredFieldValidator

Comment: Check it out on this URL : http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=Datetime

Comment: [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} PM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315376/regular-expression-for-date-time-format-mm-dd-yy-hhmmss-am-pm-in-asp-net-reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[12])/(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])/[0-9]{4}\s(?:0[0-9]|1[01]):(?:[0-5][0-9])\s(?:AM|PM)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[01]\d/[0-3]\d/2\d{3}\s[01]\d:[0-5]\d\s[AP]M
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "g", new CultureInfo("en-us"), DateTimeStyle.None, out date))
   //Match
```

Comment: i am using required field validator .