# MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM date validation regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, date, datetime

I am trying to validate a date in format  MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM  in javascript. I am unable to find any good answer tried other results but did not work. This issue has been asked for asp.net but not with javascript in the following question:

[Regular expression for date time format "MM/DD/YY HH:mm:ss AM/PM" in asp.net regular expression validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315376/regular-expression-for-date-time-format-mm-dd-yy-hhmmss-am-pm-in-asp-net-reg)

but has not helped me. 
Example dates that I need to check is 
05/13/2012 12:00:00 AM

I am validating the data cells in the csv file. These cells have some dates in the above format as well. I am checking the labels to these cells. like DATE, STRING etc. I am new thus dont know how to create them myself.

Comment: Good luck getting a regex to handle leap years...

Comment: So you have someone insert a date and time in the textbox and you want to validate that?

Comment: Consider [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) which is designed for this.

Comment: I prefer ISO-8601 (year-month-day) myself :) !

Comment: @user3739658 No, actually, I am validating the data cells in the csv file. These cells have some dates in the above format as well. I am checking the labels to these cells. like DATE, STRING etc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Date validation with regular expressions in JavaScript.

The expressions below validate any date from 01-01-1900 00:00:00 AM.

Date format: **mm[/.-]dd[/.-]yyyy hh:mm:ss am|pm**

```
var r = /^(((0[13578]|1[02])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((0[13456789]|1[012])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((02)[\/\.-](0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((02)[\/\.-](29)[\/\.-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm)))$/g;

r.test('06/12/2014 12:45:56 AM'); // true
r.test('11-12-1965 06:04:34 PM'); // true
r.test('11/31/2015 11:40:00 AM'); // false
r.test('12-31-1945 01:38:09 PM'); // true
r.test('02/29/2012 09:04:10 AM'); // true [leap year]
r.test('02/29/2013 09:04:10 AM'); // false
r.test('06.12.2014 13:04:10 AM'); // false
```

Date format: **dd[/.-]mm[/.-]yyyy hh:mm:ss am|pm**

```
var r = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/\.-](0[13578]|1[02])[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\/\.-](0[13456789]|1[012])[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((29)[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm)))$/g;

r.test('12/06/2014 12:45:56 AM'); // true
r.test('12-11-1965 06:04:34 PM'); // true
r.test('31/11/2015 11:40:00 AM'); // false
r.test('21-12-1945 01:38:09 PM'); // true
r.test('29/02/2012 09:04:10 AM'); // true [leap year]
r.test('29/02/2013 09:04:10 AM'); // false
r.test('12.06.2014 13:04:10 AM'); // false
```

Date format: **dd[/.-]mm[/.-]yyyy hh:mm:ss**

```
var r = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/\.-](0[13578]|1[02])[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\/\.-](0[13456789]|1[012])[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|((29)[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])))$/g;

r.test('24/06/2014 15:08:05'); // true
r.test('29/02/2016 23:19:20'); // true [leap year]
r.test('29/02/2015 23:19:20'); // false
r.test('31/11/2010 10:00:02'); // false
```

Date format: **yyyy[/.-]mm[/.-]dd hh:mm:ss**

```
var r = /^((((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13578]|1[02])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13456789]|1[012])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](29)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])))$/g;

r.test('2014-06-24 15:49:05'); // true
r.test('2016-02-29 23:19:20'); // true [leap year]
r.test('2015/02/29 23:19:20'); // false
r.test('2010.11.31 10:00:02'); // false
r.test('1956.10.12 24:10:02'); // false
```

Comment: can help for dd[/.-]mmm[/.-]yyyy hh:mm:ss for the same case? - hex494D49

Comment: Second regex has problem, it would pass on invalid date like "12/06/2014 12:95:90 AM".
To solve the issue (0[0-9]|[1-59]\d) should change to [0-5][0-9].