# bootstrap validation date DD.MM.YYYY jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I want to validate my first field on the form `createViewModal`, `datepickerCreateModal` in `dd.mm.yyyy` format. I was searching for some regex and I found it:

```
/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d/
```

But it seems that this regEX is not quite good - it pulls just two digits from a year (`"20"` instead of `"2016"`)

Can you write me a full regex for `dd.mm.yyyy` (*11.05.2016*)? I think I will be able to create callback function with this regex through bootstrap validator.

If someone already has this regex or a similar solution, I would be happy to hear it!

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New SAR</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="formregister">
          <form action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="createViewModal">
            <p class="qc-errmsg" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</p>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerCreateModal" name="Date" placeholder="Date">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Client" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Client</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Client1", (SelectList)ViewBag.ClientID, "", new { @class = "form-control", tabindex = "1", id = "client" })
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="EventType" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Event Type</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Eventtype", (SelectList)ViewBag.EventTypeID, "", new { @class = "form-control", tabindex = "2", id = "event" })
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="button" class="close1 btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" value="cart" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- form register -->
        <div id="successfulpost" style="font: bold 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ff0000; display: none;">
          <p class="jst-txt">
            <span>Thank you,</span> for showing your Interest !!
          </p>
          <p class="jst-txt">Our property advisor shall get in touch with you very shortly..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- model body-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(function () {
      $('#createViewModal').bind('show', function () {
          $("#datepickerCreateModal").val($(this).val() + ".");
      });
  });
  function clearCreateModal() {
      $('#event').val(0);
      $('#client').val(0);
      $('#datepickerCreateModal').val("");
      $('#datepickerCreateModal').focus();
  }
  $('.close,.close1').click(function () {
      $('#client').val(0);
      $('#event').val(0);
      $('#datepickerCreateModal').val('');
      $('#createViewModal').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
  });
  $('#dateFrom, #dateTo,#datepickerCreateModal,#datepickerEditModal').datepicker({
      todayBtn: "linked",
      daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
      calendarWeeks: true,
      autoclose: true,
      format: "dd.mm.yyyy"
  });
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
          var minDate = $('#datepicker10').val();
          var maxDate = $('#datepicker11').val();
          var ageInputs = data[1].split('.');
          var age = new Date(ageInputs[2], ageInputs[1] - 1, ageInputs[0]);
          //var getdate = date.getDate();
          var min;
          if (minDate.indexOf(".") > -1) {
              var input = minDate.split('.');
              var count = input.length;
              if (count > 2) {
                  min = new Date(input[2], input[1] - 1, input[0]);
              }
          }
          var max = new Date(maxDate.split('.')[2], maxDate.split('.')[1] - 1, maxDate.split('.')[0]);
          if ((isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
          (isNaN(min) && age <= max) ||
          (min <= age && isNaN(max)) ||
          (min <= age && age <= max)) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
  );
  var t;
  $(document).ready(function () {
      'use strict';
      $('#createViewModal').bootstrapValidator({
          // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
          feedbackIcons: {
              valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
              invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
              validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
          },
          fields: {
              Date: {
                  message: 'Date is not valid',
                  validators: {
                      notEmpty: {
                          message: 'Date  is required and cannot be empty'
                          //},
                          //stringLength: {
                          //    min: 6,
                          //    max: 30,
                          //    message: 'The Album Name  must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                          //},
                          //regexp: {
                          //    regexp: /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d/,
                          //    message: 'The Album Name  can only consist of alphabetical and number'
                      }

                  }

                  //form.submit();
              },
              Client1: {
                  message: 'Client is not valid',
                  validators: {
                      notEmpty: {
                          message: 'Client  is required and cannot be empty'
                      }
                  }
              },
              Eventtype: {
                  message: 'Event type is not valid',
                  validators: {
                      notEmpty: {
                          message: 'Event type  is required and cannot be empty'
                      }
                  }
              }

          }
      }).on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
          // Prevent form submission
          //$('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
          $('#createViewModal').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

          // Prevent form submission
          e.preventDefault();

          // Get the form instance
          var $form = $(e.target);

          // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
          var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

          // Use Ajax to submit form data
          $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function (result) {
              console.log(result);
          }, 'json');

          $.ajax({... });
          // Do whatever you want here ...
      });
      t = $('#example').DataTable({
          "iDisplayLength": 1000,
          //dom: 'Bfrtip',
          buttons: [
              'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
          ],
          "columnDefs": [
              {
                  "targets": [0],
                  "visible": false,
                  "searchable": false
              },
              { "width": "200px", "targets": 6 }
          ]
      });
      yadcf.init(t,
          [
              {
                  column_number: 0,
                  filter_type: "multi_select",
                  select_type: 'select2'
              },
              {
                  column_number: 3,
                  filter_type: "multi_select",
                  select_type: 'chosen'
              },
              {
                  column_number: 4,
                  filter_type: "multi_select",
                  select_type: 'chosen'
              }
          ]
      );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: *So, I want regex for a date fromat dd.mm.yyyy (29.04.2016).* - haven't you got it yet? The answer below is accepted.

Comment: Yes? What is the problem?

Comment: The fastest way is `(19\d\d|20\d\d)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First try is always `\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d`.

It's too wide, obviously. Let's polish it.

`^(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.((?:19|20)\d\d)$`

It still has false positives with like `31.02.1999` dates

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your code, I've tested it just now here `https://regex101.com/r/qH2rX2/1` and it seems that doesn't work..

Comment: It works, just no captured groups. I add some. =) Check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qH2rX2/2)

Comment: Thanks!! That I was looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

The reason it pulls just the first two digits of the year is that they are the only ones in the third capturing group. To fix that, you can just include the remaining two digits in the enclosing third `()`:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d
                                           ^     ^
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19\d\d|20\d\d)
                                           ^             ^
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/kF6gG3/2)

Mystery solved.

---

With that said, if you want perfect validation with different days per month, leap years and what not, let me offer you a slight variation on a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32054826/2423164). **Ready?**

```
((?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?=\.(?:0[13578]|1[02]))|(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(?=\.(?:0[469]|11))|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|29(?=\.\d{2}\.\d*(?:(?:(?!\d{2}00)(?=\d{2}(?:[13579][26]|[02468][048])))|(?=(?:[13579][26]|[02468][048])00))\d{4}(?!\d)))(?=\.02))\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4,})
```

[Experiment yourself](https://regex101.com/r/oY0nW1/4)

***Ah, the humanity!***

Long story short - yea, it is indeed complex. Read the original answer if you want more insight.

---

Alternatively, you could use the way shorter (but still cumbersome) regex that validates correctly everything, except for leap years:

```
((?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?=\.(?:0[13578]|1[02]))|(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(?=\.(?:0[469]|11))|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-9])(?=\.02))\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4,})
```

[Experiment yourself](https://regex101.com/r/aN0vS1/1)

Comment: Tested: this one seems to be the only answer that doesn't consider 30.02.2016 or 31.04.2016 as a match. As mentioned by @ndn, for 29.02.2015 and alike you still would have to do a check via JS in the browser or with whatever language used on the backend/server side.

Comment: @Dr.Rhino, actually the longer regex that I posted handles leap years, even the century rules. (:

Comment: I checked again and yes, you are right - the that is posted right before "_Ah, the humanity_" only matches real dates - so 29.02.2015 is not a match with this version of your regex. For me, this one is the best answer +1.

Comment: I like more `previous answer of mine`, especially `tldr` part, + anyway ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this regex:

It works for me

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

if you are using textbox then try to use 
[jQuery masking](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: Still I have an error.. please find this link as testlink `https://regex101.com/r/oP8cE5/1`